# Java Function as Parameter

Tags: java

I am trying to add key press events to my library, so is it possible to pass a function as a parameter to one of my library's classes, then when my library needs to fire off that function?

example:

```
Library lib = new Library();
lib.myAction(function(){
    // Do some java stuff here
});
```

So with that, when my library see something take place, such as a key press, it will fire off that function. If you have every worked with JavaScript you can do this (Really common with jQuery), and I would like to have the same effect but with Java.

Comment: perhaps you could create an `enum` that represent each `function()` then pass that?

Comment: The way you can handle it in Java now (without lambda's in JDK8) is to implement `Command` or `Strategy` design pattern

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there's no direct equivalent of that in Java. The closest you can get is to have an interface or abstract class, and then use anonymous inner class to implement/extend it:

```
lib.myAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // Do something here
    }
});
```

This should be made much simpler by Java 8's [lambda expression support](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335).

Comment: We all hope for such features in the next java version, whenever it will come.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way for this in Java. However you can pass a Method object (the method must be static) to your *myAction* function and invoke the passed method in it as follows:

```
public Object myAction(Method m, Object... args) {
    return m.invoke(args);
}
```

Note that the *args* parameter is the parameter list of the passed method.

For example, suppose you have a class *A* and a static method *sampleMethod(String s)* defined in A. You can call your *myAction* method as follows:

```
lib.myAction(A.class.getMethod("sampleMethod", String.class), "Value of parameter s");
```

If your *sampleMethod* is parameterless then you can omit the second parameter:

```
lib.myAction(A.class.getMethod("sampleMethod", String.class));
```